# Using html with ?: operator

Tags: c#, asp-classic, operator-keyword, concatenation

I am trying to show/hide an image link based on the server data but can't seem to get the html right in this ?: operator. I'm not a traditional .net dev so this one is stumping me.

```
<td>
    <p>
        <%# (Eval("attachment").ToString() == "No file attached") 
            ? "&nbsp;" 
            :  <a href='files/<%# Eval("attachment")%>'>
                <img src='images/geticon.png' alt='Attachment image' />
               </a> %>
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: The operator is called the *conditional operator* (sometimes the *ternary operator*). With those keywords in hand, a quick search should reveal the answer. I am not familiar with ASP classic myself , you see.

Comment: classic-asp / C# ? since when

Comment: I took some liberties with adding newlines into the code. Hopefully it still works and makes more sense than a single long line.

Comment: What exactly are you getting for a problem?

Comment: Are you missing quotes on the false expression? (Or is that not required in the ASP parser?)

Comment: @bowlturner I get server errors when this runs as is.

Comment: @TheRanch, what errors are they? Please include that in your post.

Comment: This works: "<%# (Eval("attachment").ToString() == "No file attached") ? "&nbsp;" :  "<a href='files/'><img src='images/geticon.png' alt='Attachment image' /></a>" %>" But notice that I no longer have the db info for the href after 'files/'. That is what is tripping it up.

Comment: @TheRanch - Your issue is because your double escaping the data bind expression (e.g. `<%#`). Look at my updated answer

Comment: You really need to learn the difference between [tag:asp-classic] and [tag:asp.net].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a shorthand way of doing an `if/else` statement. It works like this:

```
string does3equal3 = 3 == 3 ? "3 does equal 3" : "3 does not equal 3. Huh?"
```

This expressions starts on the left of the `?` and expects a boolean expression. `3 == 3` simplifies to `true`. Since the expression on the left evaluates to `true`, then the expression in between the `?` and `:` gets returned. If the expression were to evaluate to `false`, then the expression after the `:` gets returned.

**EDIT**

To fix your issue, try this instead:

```
<%# (Eval("attachment").ToString() == "No file attached") 
? "&nbsp;" : "<a href='files/" + Eval("attachment") + "'><img src='images/geticon.png' alt='Attachment image' /></a>" %>
```

Your problem was 2-fold. First, you didn't have your `false` expression surrounded in quotes. Second, you were trying to nest two data binding expessions (e.g. `<%# %>`). You can't do this, nor do you need to since you were already "escaped".

Comment: I know how it works. My problem is having the html show up and how to handle that using asp c# inline.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something to do with the second data binding. In my code had the concatenation correct at one point but not the data binding. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

`:?` is the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), which basically serve as a short if-clause.

```
condition? a : b
//is equivalent of 

if (condition)
    a
else 
    b
```

Comment: This works: <td>
    <p>
        <%# (Eval("attachment").ToString() == "No file attached") 
            ? "&nbsp;" 
            :  "image here" %>
    </p>
</td>

Answer (score 0):

please check if the ternary operator is supported at all with a very basic example.

`<%# true ? "true" : "false" %>` or something like that.

And of course also with false.

Then start expanding the complexity of the condition and later the final markup to display.

Comment: I tested that first and it does work. If I remove the html after the ":" and replace it with a string it works.

Comment: Have you tried putting the HTML after the : in quotes?

Comment: @bowlturner I have. I also tried concatonating the entire html without success.